# Wrapping JSF components with DIV

Tags: jsf

I have DIV element with a header style enclosing a h:outputText but when the page renders i see the HTML is formed in such a  way that my div doesnot contain the label generated by the h:outputText instead i see the label above my DIV . Am i doing it wrong? i tried f:verbatim but didn't help either

Comment: In future questions, please explicitly mention JSF version used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question history you're using the ancient JSF 1.1. The `<f:verbatim>` way should work. Perhaps you've enclosed JSF components inside `<f:verbatim>`. You should not do that. It should only contain raw HTML.

```
<f:verbatim><div></f:verbatim>
    <h:outputText value="Some text." />
<f:verbatim></div></f:verbatim>
```

Since JSF 1.2 the `<f:verbatim>` is not necessary anymore. JSF 1.2 should work on all environments where JSF 1.1 is been used. I strongly recommend to upgrade.

#### See also:

- [Mix HTML and JSF in a JSF subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020610/mix-html-and-jsf-in-a-jsf-subview)
- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0) (a bit of history)